# Can I redirect a failed sidekiq worker for investigation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I am using Sidekiq with my Rails app and have about 30 workers that kick off in random orders depending on the tasks clicked on by the user in the rails app. Sometimes, a sidekiq job fails and I'll have to shut down sidekiq and investigate the error manually, which consequently interrupts all workers (initiated by that user and any other user)

I just implemented a middleware so that I can finally call a method every time a sidekiq job fails; however, now I'm wondering if there's a way that I could re-run that job in a *different* queue (let's say "retry_queue").

Right now, my sidekiq workers start off like this:

```
class TestingWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: Rails.env.to_sym
```

This basically uses whatever queue the environment is running in (e.g. development or production). However, I'm not sure how to accomplish my goal given this or any other setup.

So my questions are:

1. How can I redirect a failed sidekiq job to another queue from this middleware method that captures failed sidekiq workers?
2. After redirecting it to another queue, how can I re-design the sidekiq job to understand this?

Ideally, if I could somehow change this:

```
sidekiq_options queue: Rails.env.to_sym
```

to something like this:

```
sidekiq_options queue: [something here].include? "retry_queue" ? :retry_queue : Rails.env.to_sym
```

Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jobs that have failed all of their retries then go into the dead set and the Dead tab in the Web UI. See the Error Handling wiki page.

Comment: Thanks Mike! Got this all up and running now. Very cool.